How can I get MS Project to display calendar days for duration rather than working days?
I've got start and end dates defined for activities in MS Project (latest Office 365 edition), and have set the calendar to "none" and tried both "ignore calendar" checked and unchecked to try to get duration to reflect calendar days rather than working days for tasks with duration. Not matter what I do, though, the duration always seems to be in working days (e.g. 5 business days per week) so for example a 3mos task shows as 60d, 4mos shows as 93d?, etc.
Do I need to define a custom calendar, or is there a simpler way to make Project show calendar duration rather than work weeks or person hours by default as "duration?"

Use elapsed durations such as  60ed to use calendar days rather than working days.

@RachelHettinger ed or edays being "Elapsed Days" I take it? I couldn't find that documented in Project, but will certainly give it a try and see if it works on my edition. Thanks for the suggestion; I'll let you know what happens.

@RachelHettinger Sorry it took so long to respond to you on this one. If you want to post your comment as an answer—your suggestion does work—especially if you have a link to any supporting documents (I tried but couldn't find it documented anywhere) I'd love to upvote and accept it as an answer.

have you tried setting up your own calendar with 365 working days ?

For this particular question, I would recommend creating a custom calendar that has no non-working days:

Then either set that as the base calendar of the project:

Or set it as the Task Calendar of the tasks you want to observe it:

I would highly recommend just using the standard 8 hour work day, NOT 24 hours (which is what eDays does)

This is because MS Project has other settings that determine how many hours constitutes a 'day' other than what is set for the calendar. Save yourself a headache and just use the standard 8 hour time like the image above.

While I appreciate your answer, and it may help someone else who has a calendar-based or resource-based scheduling issue, my problem was addressed by using edays ("elapsed days") rather than calendar- or effort-driven scheduling. Kudos on the easy to follow answer with clear images, though!

@ToddA.Jacobs Just know that edays assumes a 24 hour working day, rather than a standard 8 hour work day.
